# elasticsearch two node cluster on a standalone server

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have an ELK stack running on a single server.  The elasticsearch health query is showing me two nodes:

`curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty
{
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "status" : "green",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 2,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 2,
  "active_primary_shards" : 901,
  "active_shards" : 1802,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 100.0
}`

From what I can tell there is a node on port 9200 and a node on port 9300.

As I only have one server, I don't think I need two nodes.  Can I safely delete one on these nodes and if so how ?

Comment: Tell me, how do you run elasticsearch nodes?

Comment: sorry, I don't understand what you're asking?.  This is just a very simple out of the box installation. I installed the elasticsearch package and ran: service elasticsearsh start.

Comment: active_primary_shards * number_of_nodes = active_shards => you can safely delete one of these nodes.
run in terminal 'sudo ps -ef | grep elasticsearch' - it will help to find the PID for elasticsearch and then just kill one of elasticsearch

Answer (score 0):

Each ElasticSearch node will open 2 ports by default: 9200 for http and 9300 for transport protocol.

What's going on here is that you are actually running *another* ElasticSearch instance in the same local network (maybe the same computer but definitely with different ports).

Nodes will join the cluster by name (`elasticsearch` in your case).

To find out about your cluster's nodes, run the following query:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_nodes?pretty'
```

To avoid unwanted nodes joining a cluster, choose an appropriate cluster name in your ElasticSearch config file (`/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml`); never leave the default.

After stopping the rogue node and changing the cluster name in the good node, most probably your cluster state will turn yellow, as all recovery shards will be unassigned. That's no problem as long as you don't need high availability.

Comment: Thank you for the information.  I ran the command you suggested and both nodes are on the same server on different ports - one on 9300 and one on 9301

`"bpxZ0OECQ0GaHfCd0NECRQ" : {
      "name" : "Lorelei II",
      "transport_address" : "10.32.224.120:9300",
"Z0h3pC_HSzy9l88lhMYWqA" : {
      "name" : "Goldbug",
      "transport_address" : "10.32.224.120:9301",`

Comment: Maybe you started one of them directly from the command line and the other was run as a service (init.d or whatever your operating system is using).

Anyway, you should stop one of them and make sure they are not sharing config or data files.